# Extracting multiple values after an exact string using regular expresions

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, search, match

I have 100s of .txt/.sed files with lots of lines in each.

Sample input file:

```
Time: 10:34:51.49,15:21:39.24
Box Temperature (K): 32.82,8.88,-10.07
Silicon Temperature (K): 10.90,9.88
Voltage: 7.52,7.41
Dark Mode: AUTO,AUTO
Radiometric Calibration: RADIANCE
Units: W/m^2/sr/nm
GPS Time: n/a
Satellites: n/a
Channels: 1024
```

Desired output:

```
Time             15:21:39.24
Box Temp         32.82
                  8.88
                -10.07
Si Temp          10.90
                  9.88
```

I was trying to write the code for identifying the string and then making a list of the values and then later tackle arranging them into a DataFrame followed by writing them to a .csv file.
Sample code

```
testtxt = 'Temperature (K): 32.82,8.88,-10.07,32.66,8.94,-10.07'
exp = r'^Temperature (K):(\s*) ([0-9.]+)([0-9.]+), ([0-9.-]+) , (-[0-9-.]+),([0-9-.]+) , ([0-9-.]+),(-[0-9-.]+)'
regexp = re.compile(exp)
my_temp = regexp.search(txt)
print(my_temp.group(0))
```

ERROR:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Basically, it finds no match!

Clarification: I want an efficient way to only extract the Time and Temperature values, not the others. It would be great to be able to stop scanning the files once those are found since each file has over 500 lines and I have lots of them.

Comment: What is the rule for the time?

Comment: Try using the .split() method to get the results you want. Split each string by "," because each result you want is separated by commas.

Comment: @RohanB I am REALLY new with regexp, can you give an example of what you are talking about? Doesn't it take the commas in the expression as literal terms now?

Comment: @Jan I tried doing that in MATLAB so the syntax might be a little different and it is highly inefficient atm: 'expr = '(?<=Time\s*:\s*(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{2},))(?<your_field>(.*))'; '

Comment: @Brain_overflowed I am sorry, I cannot give a very good example as I am not very good with regexp either.

Comment: Your test text has "Temperature (K)", but your regular expression is looking for "Temperature (C)". Last I checked, "(K)" doesn't match "(C)".

Comment: @JimMischel lol I wish that was the solution!! that is a typo

Comment: So do you just want the last entry in the time row? And do you want the output tab-delimited like you have shown?

Comment: @rahlf23 I do want only the last entry in the time row and the output can be in .csv format

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use string.startswith() to determine if the string starts with "Box Temperature (K)", or whatever. Once you find that, get the rest of the string, parse it as a CSV, and then validate each of the components. Trying to do this all with regular expressions is more trouble than it's worth.

If you want to have the code stop once it's found everything, just set flags for the things you want to find, and once all the flags are set you can exit. Something like:

```
foundTime = 0
foundBoxTemp = 0
foundSiTemp = 0
while (not end of file AND (foundTime == 0 || foundBoxTemp == 0 || foundSiTemp == 0))
    if (line.startswith("Box Temperature (K):"))
        // parse and output
    else if (line.startswith("Time:"))
        // parse and output
    else ....
```

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how can I add each single value in a list form?

Comment: The whole point was to be able to extract the values so, sorry the psuedocode doesn't really help. I understand the logic, just having trouble in the implementation due to being new